# OnePlus 5 Soft Brick

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking, bootloader-lock, oneplus-5

I have a OnePlus 5 and it won't boot. The phone is stuck on a black screen and blue LED (can't boot) since 20 days ago, and I tried everything I saw on the web to make it boot again.

I tried :

- to flash the recovery with the original one
- to flash the Oxygen OS and the Hydrogen OS via fastboot (authorized even with a locked bootloader)
- to use MSMDownloadTool (a tool I found on the web, used by the support of OnePlus to reinstall bricked phones.

...but nothing helped.

I'm now with my OP5 soft-bricked, but since I used MSMDownloadTool, it locked itself (the tool locked the bootloader) and I can't flash again with fastboot (except the official ROM but still won't boot) nor adb. I tried `fastboot oem unlock` but I got an error (because I can't go on the developer's options due to the phone not loading): `FAILED (remote: Flashing Unlock is not allowed)`

If it gets you some info, I did `fastboot oem device-info` and got this result:

```
(bootloader) Verity mode: enforcing
(bootloader) Device unlocked: false
(bootloader) Device critical unlocked: false
(bootloader) Charger screen enabled: true
(bootloader) enable_dm_verity: true
(bootloader) have_console: false
(bootloader) selinux_type: SELINUX_TYPE_INVALID
(bootloader) boot_mode: NORMAL_MODE
(bootloader) kmemleak_detect: false
(bootloader) force_training: 0
(bootloader) mount_tempfs: 0
OKAY [  0.001s]
Finished. Total time: 0.002s
```

Is there any solution to be sure to write again everything on the OP5? (it seems that the MSMDownloadTool and fastboot won't erase everything as the OP5 finishes properly new installation but boot loop every time).

The present state of the OP5: bootloader locked, official recovery working, official ROM installed but won't boot.

I'm on Mac and Windows btw.

I followed numerous tutorials like this one :
[Unbrick tool OnePlus 5](https://forum.xda-developers.com/oneplus-5/how-to/unbrick-tool-oneplus-5-t3648169)

Comment: It sounds to me like the boot image is the one causing you problems. Since at no point should a phone with default recovery working and official system not boot. Have you heard about the kernel and porting of images. This is exactly what you may need to do. For any reason, when flashing any OS.  Ensure you port any OS's boot image by the original image that was in phone. Since you can flash in the OS, if your flash tool supports a firmware that can be extracted, you can look for a TWRP recovery, replace the one in firmware with the TWRP image and reflash. This will get you an environment...

Comment: ...to install other OS on. But consequently. If you can get hands on the stock boot image. You can replace any OS's kernel with its stock. For example me I use MTKBoot for Windows to port images.

Comment: Thank you @ThallyAce, can you explain to me or show me a tutorial for that?
I'm at the point where I'll try anything to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a good workaround for the situation above. Since you were able to flash the phone, that means the MSNFlashTool is well configured in your computer. Now what I want you to think about is how you can flash a custom recovery image into the phone so that you can even get the phone alive by a third party OS like Lineage and anything.

After downloading the firmware file and starting flashing, the MSMTool writes the current progress in the progress window writing what it's flashing in the phone. Notably the userdata.img is one of the files you recognize since it is somehow big and doesn't flash quickly.

Consequently many data partitions exist in the phones memory, like the:

1. system.img
2. cache.img
3. boot.img
4. recovery.img

These are the essentials in any system, remember these are not all but these are the compulsory in any system. I'm sure the flash file is an archive that you can open with rar. It sometimes can be an archive containing an archive so you have to extract it twice incase you don't see these img files. Once opened in rar take note on what type of archive is the firmware file. It can be:

1. zip
2. tar
3. 7z
4. rar
5. gz
6. gzip

And many more other types. Hope you remember this. Look for a compatible custom recovery image like twrp and replace it with the recovery.img or alternatively the boot.img if you miss the recovery in the firmware. If there are checksums like the md5, sha256 or any other sums to verify the integrity of files, regenerate and replace them, then repack the firmware with the same compression type as it was and flash the phone using it and you shall have teamwin recovery as your default recovery or boot.

Use the recovery to load third party OS and if you get the OS booting use it to unlock bootloader for futher fastboot actions or you can even use the new OS if you're convenient with it

Note: Ensure the recovery image is specifically made for your device model. If you have any trouble finding the appropriate recovery for your specific phone model, I can make you a download link for it after you give me exact specifications of your phone.

Hope it helps you

Comment: So I have been following closely how it's flashing software works. I saw the Flash Tool writing loading the userdata.img on a progress window. Does that mean other partitions don't come in the firmware as imaged files?

Comment: No, the others partitions are actually flash with the tool. As I comment (on the upper post) the tool has a file .OPS I don't know if I can change the boot.img on it or not.

Comment: If you extracted and got the boot image. You can make a copy of your firmware and replace the boot img with a twrp img instead. Remember when navigating the system using winrar, it can open the ops file and tell you what archive it is. And replacing any file by drag and drop updates the archive in the same compression type. So this will make it easy to replace and repack (updating). And then I'm sure after changing that file the message digest sum is altered and this means you will regenerate any md5 or sha256 sum of the ops file usually a text file to make the flash tool not to ignore file

Comment: That's when I'm assuming any flash tool must check verification of the flash files by their checksums so as not to flash a corrupt file

Comment: I tried with winrar but it doesn't recognise the format file .OPS
Is there any advanced tool in winrar that I don't know the existence?

Comment: I don't know any other advanced tool in it. It was supposed to automatically recognize the file if it was an archive which it now seems it's not

Comment: I think it's the proprietary format from OnePlus. I found this: https://github.com/bkerler/oppo_decrypt
maybe it'll help.

Comment: Shall have to try that

Comment: It didn't work...

Comment: I shall alert you if I find an extraction algorithm